# Vue.js custom component with HTML <select> and v-model (W3C compliant)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, html-select, v-model

I'm new to Vue.js (using Nuxt.js) and what I'm trying to achieve is to have a Select component that I can reuse everywhere and is W3C compliant.

With the help of @Jasmonate answers, I managed to create this component, it's working. But the `value` attribute is still visible in the source code and so isn't W3C compliant. Maybe the problem is coming from somewhere else in the project ?!

Parent component

```
<custom-select
  :options="options"
  v-model="selectedOption"
></custom-select>
<span>Selected : {{ selectedOption }}</span>

<script>
  data() {
    return {
      selectedOption: "A",
      options: [
        { label: "One", value: "A" },
        { label: "Two", value: "B" },
        { label: "Three", value: "C" }
      ],
    };
  }
</script>
```

custom-select.vue

```
<template>
  <select :value="value" @input="clicked">
    <option
      v-for="option in options"
      :key="option.label"
      :value="option.value"
    >
      {{ option.label }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      value: {
        required: true
      },
      options: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
      }
    },
    methods: {
      clicked($event) {
        this.$emit("input", $event.target.value);
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

I read those documentation pages:

- [Form Input Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select)
- [Components Basics](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

And also looked around the web to find example of v-model in a custom component, but it's always about the input tag. The only example I found about a custom select with v-model isn't actually a select tag, like the [Vue Select](https://vue-select.org/) plugin or [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952232/vue-js-custom-select-component-with-v-model) on StackOverflow.

Comment: What's your question? Are you trying to create a custom form component that uses a `<select>` internally? If so, can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer and sorry for my not native English, I might have not explain myself well. I am trying to create a custom Select component only.
I'm going to edit my first message to add one of the many code I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model` is syntax sugar. By default, the value is a prop that has the name `value`, and it changes (two-way-binding) whenever the event `input` is emitted.

Also, v-model is bound on the `select` element, not `option`.

Your code can be modified as such:

```html
<template>
  <select :value="value" @input="clicked">
    <option
      v-for="option in options"
      :key="option.label"
      :value="option.value"
    >
      {{ option.label }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      value: {
        required: true
      },
      options: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
      }
    },
    methods: {
      clicked($event) {
        this.$emit('input', $event.target.value);
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Documentation here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

You can also change the prop name and event name that `v-model` uses, see: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model

Comment: Hi @Jasmonate and thanks for your answer. I edited the code in my first message but it still doesn't work. I probably don't understand the links between `option.value` in option, `value` in props and `$event` :s
Does `$event` shoot the `option.value` or am I suppose to do something more in the method? In the Vue.js example they wrote `$event.target.value`

If I do the html-select tag directly in the parent component, the `selectedOption` is updated correctly.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, I haven't been using native `select` in a while. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: No worries @Jasmonate, thanks for taking the time to help me! So I modified my code with your corrections and yes it works. But if I want to have a W3C valid code it doesn't accept value on select tag.

`Error: Attribute value not allowed on element select at this point.
<select value="A" data-v-e3eecde6><option>...`

So I wonder if there is another way to do it?

Comment: Vue uses virtual dom, and should strip component properties from HTML element attributes if they are declared as props. I've tried to reproduce this in my local environment (vue@2.6.0) and the `value` attribute was stripped from `<select>`. Make sure you have added `value` to the `props` object in your component.

Comment: If you want to strip all additional attributes, you can try this: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs example: `export default {  inheritAttrs: false, data() { ... }  }`

Comment: Hi @Jasmonate, thanks a lot for trying on your side. So it appears that I might have a problem in the all project (using Nuxt 2.10.2, don't know if it can change something). Because `value` is in `props` for the `custom-select` but when I look at the source code after a `npm run dev` I still have the attribute `value` in the `select` tag but not the `@input`.

I added `inheritAttrs: false` as you suggest on the `custom-select` but still got the `value` attribute!

Comment: I checked again today. If I inspect the element in browser, you're correct `value` is no longer in the `<select>` tag but if I display the source code with a right click, there it's still here. After refering to this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070190/is-the-html-shown-via-view-source-different-from-the-html-shown-in-firebug-d it's normal that it's different.
I wonder now which source code I'm suppose to feed an HTML5 validator...